# Axis ticks labels in ggraph dendrogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggraph

I started playing with the ggraph package since it looks very promising in terms of extra features it adds to the available plots of network graphs (see [this tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggraph/vignettes/Edges.html)). However, testing something fairly trivial, I'm already stuck. What I basically want to do is reproduce a simple dendrogram:

```
ArrestsDen <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(USArrests[1:5,])))
plot(ArrestsDen)
```

[image: dendrogram plot in base]

But this is how it looks in ggraph:

```
library(ggraph)
ggraph(ArrestsDen, 'dendrogram') +
  geom_edge_elbow()
```

[image: ggraph dendrogram plot]

Instead of axis tick labels, it shows just 0,1,2 etc.. I already tried the usual ggplot2 "tricks" but without success:

```
ggraph(ArrestsDen, 'dendrogram') +
  geom_edge_elbow() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = labels)

# create labels manually
labs <- labels(ArrestsDen)
names(labs) <- as.character(1:length(labels(ArrestsDen)))
class(labs)

ggraph(ArrestsDen, 'dendrogram') +
  geom_edge_elbow() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = labs)
```

[image: ggraph dendrogram plot2]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try that:

```
  ggraph(ArrestsDen, 'dendrogram') +
    geom_edge_elbow() + 
    theme_bw() + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), label=c("Ark","Arizona","Cal", "Alab", "Alaska"))
```

Comment: Thanks! I could have sworn I had already tried that! This is what I settled on: `ggraph(ArrestsDen, 'dendrogram') +
  geom_edge_elbow() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = as.numeric(names(labs))-1, label=labs) +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))`